# SP Designer 2010 Copy WF Variable from One WF to Another WF?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to copy a WF variable from one WF to another WF?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so, perhaps there is a shorter way but i use this one:

1. You have two WF: WF1 and WF2
2. WF1 has one variable named var1 and connected to the List1
3. Create a temp list named TempList that just have one column, for example; title
4. Create another WF named WF2 and connect to the TempList
5. WF2 will started when an item added to the list
6. WF2 has a variable named var2
7. In WF1, add var1's value to TempList
8. When TempList has new item, WF2 will start, so in WF2 you can get the var1's value from TempList and you can set it to the var2

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding how to set the value of the variable in WF2. It's asking me to set Field Data to Retrieve AND Find the List Item. What do I enter into the Find the List Item

Comment: @Hasan has about 90% of it in his answer, but to answer @mappingman’s second comment, consider the following:  if WF1 is acting on list item#123 and WF2 needs to get the variable that was specific to item#123, you need a second column.  You could use the ID of the list item to uniquely identify the list item that triggered WF1, then WF2 would have both the ID of the list item triggering the action for WF1 and the variable value that was to be passed to WF2.